# How to make a database request in Uniface 9.7

Tags: informix, uniface

How to make a database request in Uniface 9.7 with an Informix database?

Example:
I like to query a person with the id = 5 from the database with the columns 'name' and 'age'.

Comment: I never used Uniface, but looking at their doc, it appears they have serveral "Connectors" used to interface with databases, for Informix you can use their Iown Informix connector or one based on ODBC (which should work with all standard ODBC drivers, like the one included in Informix CSDK)
More info about those connectors here: `https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/Uniface/10/uniface/dbmsSupport/dbmsDrivers/DBMSConnectors.htm`

Comment: Thank you @jsagrera, but i need an example as an uniface code.